# Windows Systemuser can't access Github

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I've a Windows VM that is one of my Jenkins Build Agents for this setup was working fine for a couple of months, but starting this week the Github fetch failed with this error message:

```
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://{GITHUB-ENTERPRISE-URL-HERE}/{ORGANISATION-HERE}/{REPO-NAME-HERE}/
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1004)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1245)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1305)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:97)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://{GITHUB-ENTERPRISE-URL-HERE}/{ORGANISATION-HERE}/{REPO-NAME-HERE} +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Your account is suspended. Please check with your installation administrator.
fatal: unable to access 'https://{GITHUB-ENTERPRISE-URL-HERE}/{ORGANISATION-HERE}/{REPO-NAME-HERE}/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

For the actual checkout we use a functional account that has a personal access token defined in his Github settings. The functional account can still access the Github Enterprise instance just fine and I even tried cloning a repo with his access token, this also works fine (on the Jenkins Build Agent).

So I guess the errormessage is somewhat missleading, as the user seems to still have access.
I suspect that the error has something to do with the fact that the Jenkins Agent runs as the systemuser on my Windows VM.

If I try to clone a repo with a systemuser console I get the same error message, cloning it in a non-systemuser console works just fine.

For managing the git credentials I use the `manager` for the systemuser and the non-systemuser.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

### EDIT

Forgot to mention that I already tried another user and the behaviour is still the same, so it really looks like it's not the actual user that is suspended on the Github side.

Comment: _"Your account is suspended."_ - I don't think it matters if you're a super user or not. It could be that the user needs to switch authentication methods?

Comment: Just to be clear, with "user" you mean the functional account user? If you use this user as a systemuser it throws the error, if I run it in my user context with this user everything works. The same happens when I use username and password instead of the token.